# How to align Item in the middle without flex?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align Header text using flex. But the alignment does not work the way I expected.

[image]
[image]

Here are the two images of Blog and About.

These items are aligned using space-between.

```
container: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '100%',
} 
// btw, I am using material-ui class
```

However the position of text **Blog** and **About** is different due to the different size and element of the link text and three-dots icon.

How can I locate text **Blog** as same position as **About**?

Comment: Does that selector really work?  `container:` isn't a valid selector. Also, the images posted are not very useful, so include relevant HTML as well. In fact read  how to make a [mcve].

Comment: the duplicate cover the flexbox and css grid solution

Comment: @zer00ne I did not show full usage of makeStyles supported by material-ui css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grid to make 3 even columns and then it won't care about even spacing between the elements and will keep them where you want them.

Then align the text in the center for the middle column and on the right for the right column.

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
}

.center-div{
    text-align: center;
}

.right-div {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: good. I could use grid supported by material-ui

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bootstrap Horizontal alignment. Centered with .justify-content-center:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute, and  margin: auto auto;

Another alternative using flex, you can add an empty element (dummy elemet) something like "" where the three dots are, so it will have the same relative center as the other one, you can add some padding to the Back to about to make it the same width as the Back To blog list.

Hope this helped.